# JSON Parse issue with array

Tags: javascript

i am doing something wrong, i am passing array to html element and setting, data attribute. When i console log array got this.

[image]

Then doing

```
<img class="d-block w-100" data-title="'+JSON.stringify(value.image_tree_titles) +'" />
```

in html looks like this

[image]

But when i try JSON.Parse(), got sintax error with open bracket? Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `data-title="[{"` is what it probably thinks your attribute is. See how the coloring is all messed up? Instead of just writing `json.stringify` directly in there, you should consider encoding it (bse64, for example) OR writing it as the value of a hidden input. It might be possible to safely escape those double quotes, but I wouldn't trust it

Comment: looks like it's issue with quotes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of `data-title` is delimited by double quotes (`"`), but also contains double quotes. Any time you interpolate a string literal into a template, you need to apply encoding to the string, unless you can ensure that it's safe. In this case, because it's being embedded into HTML, you'll want to apply HTML encoding.

`{"foo":"bar"}` becomes `{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}`

See the second link for how to do this encoding in javascript. Simply replacing the double quote characters is not enough.

Sources:

- [List of XML and HTML Character Entity References](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)
- [HTML-encoding in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-lost-when-attribute-read-from-input-field)

Comment: Which solutions did you try? Does the value of `data-title` look like the example with the `&`-escaping?

Answer (score -1):

Here what i did

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(title))
```

is string encoded check

```
function isEncoded(str) {
        return typeof str == "string" && decodeURIComponent(str) !== str;
    }
```

finally

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(title));
```